# Angular material table applyFilter method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a component where I display my table that comes from angular material table, and I want the search bar for that I have a method appyFilter that comes from the official doc angular material table, my search bar is on another component and this is the problem.
I don't see my mistake.

thanks for your help.

**main.component.ts**

```
data:any;

    makeRowObservable() {
            return this.service.get().pipe( map(data: myInterface[]) => data.toto.map((item: any[]) => this.transormListToMap())
        }
        
        transormListToMap() {
        
            let result = {};
            for (let i = 0; i < this.tableCols.length; i++) {
                let col = this.tableCols[i];
                let value = item[i];
                let colId = col.key;
                result[colId] = value; // here i got my result
            }
            this.data = result;
            return result;
        }
```

**main.component.html**

```
<app-tableau></app-tableau>
<app-filter [valuesData]="data"></app-filter> // this component displays my search bar
```

**filter.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event)" placeholder="Ex. ium" #input>
</mat-form-field>
```

**filter.component.ts**

```
@input valuesData;

public dataSource = MatTableDataSource<any[]>()

ngOnInit() {
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any[]>()
 this.datasource = this.valuesData
}


 applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Comment: your "TableuComponent" has no idea about the dataSource in the filter. One idea is that the dataSource belongs to the "main component" and pass as `@Input` this dataSource -not the data- to **both**: to the "TableuComponent" and to the "FilterComponent"

Comment: BTW, the syntax correct is `this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.valuesData)`. MatTableDataSource is a class with severals properties that allow filter and sort the "data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an input emitter in the filter component recieving data from **main.component.ts** and there should also be an output emitter, emitting data from the filter component to the main component. The main component should be where the dataSource is implemented in the first place. The same dataSource should be passed to child components as Inputs.

The structure should be like this:

**main comp**: (data fetch, build etc. - Parent component)

- app-tableau (mat-table - get data from main-comp) *This component will only display the table with data*
- filterComp (widget - get data from main-comp) *This component will filter and send back to the main component*

**main.component.ts**

```
data: any;
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
transormListToMap() {
  ..
  ..
  this.data = result;
  this.dataSource.data = result; // Update dataSource
  return result;
}

updateDataSource(filteredData: any){
  this.dataSource.filteredData = filteredData; // Update dataSource with filtered data from filter component
}
```

**main.component.html**

```
<app-tableau [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-tableau>
<app-filter [dataSource]="dataSource" (filteredData)="updateDataSource($event)"></app-filter>
```

**filter.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="search" (ngModelChange)="searchData()">
```

**filter.component.ts**

```
@Input() dataSource: any;  // Ideally this also should have type as MatTableDataSource
@Output() filteredData = new EventEmitter();
search: string = '';
ngOnChanges(): void {
  this.searchData();
}

searchData(): void {
  this.dataSource.filter = this.search;
  this.filteredData.emit(this.dataSource.filteredData);
}
```